# MySql Complex Multiple Table Join

Tags: mysql, join

I have Three Tables

```
Table 1       Table 2                 Table 3
id   deg       id  t1_id   name       id  t2_id  t1_id   name
101  ABC       1   202   Test 1        1   3      202    Job a
202  PQR       2   202   Test 2        2   1      101    Job b
303  XYZ       3   101   Test 3        3   2      303    job C

How write a single MySql query so that i can achieve results as Follows:

t1_name  t1_deg  t2_name t2_deg 
Test 1    PQR     Job b   ABC
Test 2    PQR     Job c   XYZ
Test 3    ABC     Job a   PQR

Thanks For Help
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Still Did not get My Solution Sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
    Table2.name,
    Table1.deg,
    Table3.name
FROM
    Table1
JOIN 
    Table2 ON Table2.t1_id = Table1.id
JOIN 
    Table3 ON Table1.id = Table3.t1_id;
```

Comment: I would expect the answer to have the same number of columns as the question.

Comment: This is good but I want table 1 deg for both my table not just one

Comment: This is missing one column

Comment: can you explain where t2_deg  is come from. because what I see is only one deg  column

Comment: Table 1 contain a deg column which is refereed in both table 2 and table 3 i want separate deg value according to their id fro both table one deg value from table 1 and another deg value for table 2 respectively

Comment: join table1 twice first with table which you already have and second with table3 to show `t2_deg`

Comment: Sorry But can you please suggest me the Query to obtain the same i am new to Sql.